# In application Insights Stack Traces in the exception table is getting logged without line numbers

Tags: azure-application-insights

following query retrieves the stack trace with line numbers as 0
exceptions

```
| sort by timestamp desc
| take 10
```

is there any flag I need to enable to get the correct line numbers

Answer (score 1):

the query in your question will give the exceptions (presuming you run the query against the `exceptions` table, not listed in the query, and the stack/line information is in the `details` column of that table.  because each actual exception telemetry could be nested/aggregate exceptions itself, you'd need to use mvexpand/etc to get info out:

```
exceptions
| project timestamp, problemId, details
| mvexpand with_itemindex=stack details // turns each item in details into its own rows with a new "stack" column
| mvexpand with_itemindex = frame details.parsedStack // turns each item in parsed stack into its own rows with new "frame" column
| extend line = details_parsedStack.line // grabs the line number out of every parsed stack, if it exists
| take 10
```

the results/behavior of that query will be very specific to your data.

Comment: Surprised no one voted this up. Helped out a lot when using in Logic App to generate an intelligent email alert. One follow up question. How would you group these by exception occurrence? The query creates rows for each stack trace item but I'd like to group them for each exception. Thanks a lot.